# AngularJS ng-true-value not working on v1.6.1

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, checkbox

So I am new to AngularJS and I was following a tutorial online where they give the following example on how to use ng-true-value and ng-false-value:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
 <head>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.24/angular.min.js"></script>
 </head>
 <body ng-app="app" ng-controller="appCtrl as vm">
  <p>
   <input type="checkbox" ng-model="vm.bw" ng-true-value="on" ng-false-value="off" />
    status: {{vm.bw}}
  </p>  
  <script>
   var app = angular.module("app", [])
   app.controller("appCtrl", function(){
    var vm = this   
   });
  </script>
 </body>
</html>
```

This works perfectly.
But the I realized they were using an old version of AngularJS (1.2.24), so I decided to change it to the current version (1.6.1) by simply changing the line

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.24/angular.min.js"></script>
```

to

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.1/angular.min.js"></script>
```

(Of course I checked if this file existed)
It turns out that this example doesn't work anymore. I click the checkbox but nothing happens.
Is there a working code for version 1.6.1?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/input/input%5Bcheckbox%5D) says everything is fine with the code you're using.
Try wrapping your

> on/off

Statements with quotes (according to the docs) has angular trying to evaluate it.

Otherwise use "true/false" without quotes and see what happens!